# Nested JSON Array throwing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" when trying to iterate through

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to figure out why my code is throwing this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

This error message references this line: "for (var j = 0; j < pluginObj.installedMimes.length; j++)"

I can't tell why this error is happening, I have checked my JSON code using JSONLint and it said there were no errors. Any help and suggestions would be appreciated!

```
var pluginsJson = {
    "installedPlugins": [
        {
            "pluginName": "Chrome PDF Viewer",
            "pluginVersion": "",
            "pluginDescription": "Portable Document Format",
            "pluginFilename": "internal-pdf-viewer",
            "installedMimes": [
                {
                    "mimeType": "application/x-google-chrome-pdf",
                    "mimeDesc": "Portable Document Format",
                    "mimeSuffixes": "pdf"
                },
                {
                    "mimeType": "application/x-nacl",
                    "mimeDesc": "Native Client Executable",
                    "mimeSuffixes": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "pluginName": "Widevine Content Decryption Module",
            "pluginVersion": "",
            "pluginDescription": "Enables Widevine licenses for playback of HTML audio/video content. (version: 1.4.8.866)",
            "pluginFilename": "widevinecdmadapter.dll"
        },
        {
            "pluginName": "Shockwave Flash",
            "pluginVersion": "",
            "pluginDescription": "Shockwave Flash 21.0 r0",
            "pluginFilename": "pepflashplayer.dll"
        },
        {
            "pluginName": "Native Client",
            "pluginVersion": "",
            "pluginDescription": "",
            "pluginFilename": "internal-nacl-plugin"
        }
    ]
};

var pluginString = "";
var pluginObj;
var mimeObj;

for (var i = 0; i < pluginsJson.installedPlugins.length; i++) {
    pluginObj = pluginsJson.installedPlugins[i];

    pluginString += pluginObj.pluginName;
    pluginString += " | ";
    pluginString += pluginObj.pluginFilename;
    pluginString += " | ";
    pluginString += pluginObj.pluginDescription;
    pluginString += " | ";
    pluginString += pluginObj.pluginVersion;
    pluginString += "<br>";

    for (var j = 0; j < pluginObj.installedMimes.length; j++) {
        mimeObj = pluginObj.installedMimes[j];

        pluginString += mimeObj.mimeType;
        pluginString += " /\ ";
        pluginString += mimeObj.mimeDesc;
        pluginString += " /\ ";
        pluginString += mimeObj.mimeSuffixes;
        pluginString += "<br>";
    }
    pluginString += "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Nvm, mihai is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because not all of your `pluginObj`'s define `installedMimes`.

You can fix this in two ways:

a) Add `"installedMimes": []` to all plugins present in the json.

b) Update your JS code to check for the existance of `installedMimes`.

```
if (pluginObj.installedMimes) {
    for (var j = 0; j < pluginObj.installedMimes.length; j++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh how did I not see that. I feel very silly. Now thanks a lot for the answer my friend!

Answer (score 0):

I see you have an `installedMimes` array only in the first `installedPlugin`, and not in the others...

I would add a test, before your inner loop:

```
if (typeof pluginObj.installedMimes !== 'undefined') {
    for (var j = 0; j < pluginObj.installedMimes.length; j++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, sorry! Just corrected answer, please remove downvote... :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I had the reputation to upvote your solution I would. Still very much appreciated!